# What items could help against fighting a dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dragons

Getting ready to battle a horde of dragons. What are the best magic weapons to fight dragons? Found arrows and some charms against dragon breath. What non-homebrew items could help?

Comment: Are you asking for items specifically tailored to help against dragons, or any items in general that work? The latter is likely too broad of a question. Similarly, would you consider magic items that simply deal a large amount of damage "helpful against a dragon" or do you want items that are, again, specifically effective against dragons despite the likely existence of flatly stroner magic items with no special effects against dragons?

Comment: The headline asks for items in general, but the body asks for "magic weapons" specifically. Are you just looking for magic weapons? Also, do you know the number, types and ages (young, adult, etc.) of the dragons you'll be facing?

Answer (score 6):

### Generally, a [Dragon Slayer](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dragon%20Slayer#content) sword and [Dragon Scale Mail](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dragon%20Scale%20Mail#content).

A Dragon Slayer gives a significant damage boost (3d6) against dragons, while Dragon Scale Mail gives advantage on saves vs breath weapons and Dragon Fear.  If it's the right color, Dragon Scale Mail can also give resistance against the dragon's breath.

### If you know the dragons' color[s], there are some other items that can give a large advantage.

If you're fighting a red, gold, or brass dragon, for example, [Efreeti Chain](https://5e.tools/items/efreeti-chain-dmg.html) will grant you immunity to its breath weapon and any other fire abilities it has.

If it's a green dragon, a [Periapt of Proof against Poison](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Periapt%20of%20Proof%20against%20Poison#content) will make you immune to its poison breath and bite.

If it's white or silver, [Boots of the Winterlands](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Boots%20of%20the%20Winterlands#content) or a [Ring of Warmth](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ring%20of%20Warmth#content) will grant resistance to its breath.

And an appropriate [Ring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-resistance) or [Armor of Resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-of-resistance) will help against any dragon with elemental abilities of that type, if you know what you're facing in advance.

Comment: There's always also the [Armor of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-of-invulnerability) if you wanted to mention that option

Answer (score 1):

## The [Dragon Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-slayer-longsword) sword

A rare magic sword ("*any sword*") from the DMG, p. 116:

> You gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. When you hit a dragon with this weapon, the dragon takes an extra 3d6 damage of the weapon's type. For the purpose of this weapon, "dragon" refers to any creature with the dragon type, including dragon turtles and wyverns.